# Listening to actions and passing parameters

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, delegates, action

I'm using Unity 2020.3.17f1, and I am working on a quest system. I want any script to be able to trigger an event, that the quest system will listen to and forward the quest progress based on that.

I am currently using System.Action trying to achieve this, but I need to pass parameters. For example, when I trigger the event OnEnemyKill, I want the listener to be able to know *which* enemy was killed.

Here is what I have set up so far:

QuestActions.cs

```
using System;

public class QuestActions
{
    public static Action<string> OnEnemyKilled;

}
```

SpacebarPresser.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpacebarPresser : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            QuestActions.OnEnemyKilled("hello");
        }
    }
}
```

QuestTracker.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class QuestTracker : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        QuestActions.OnEnemyKilled += EnemyKilled;
    }
    
    private void OnDisable()
    {
        QuestActions.OnEnemyKilled -= EnemyKilled;
    }

    private void EnemyKilled(string msg)
    {
        Debug.Log("Message");
    }


}
```

The problem with my code, is that in QuestTracker.cs, I can't figure out how to get the parameter that was used when invoking the action in SpacebarPresser.cs.

I have tried using other event-set-ups, but ran into the same problem when using delegates and events, and scriptable object events.

Comment: what happens when you replace "Message" with msg your parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value you're passing as a parameter when you invoke `OnEnemyKilled` should just be coming through as the `msg` parameter in `EnemyKilled`.

Comment: Wow. I feel stupid, I had no idea it would pass through like that - I assumed I had to add it somewhere in the OnEnable where the function subscribes to the event.